# ATG<dsp:setvalue> Trouble with setting values using JSTL

Tags: jstl, atg

Got some trouble with using jstl in atg jsp page. Added 
`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` and some library at /WEB-INF/lib (standard.jar, jstl.jar).
My web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
```

So `<dsp:getvalueof param="id" var="prodId"/>
    <c:set var="link"  value="genericproduct.jsp?id=${prodId}"/>` works fine and shows for example "genericproduct.jsp?id=prod180007",but `${prodId}` shows nothing,at the moment `<c:out value="${prodId}"/>` works. And `<dsp:setvalue bean="CustomFormHandler.errorURL" value="genericproduct.jsp?id=${prodId}"/>` doesn't works - "genericproduct.jsp?id=${prodId}". Version of JSTL 1.0, application runs on jboss 4.0.5GA.I look forward to your reply.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>`